# Fill Factor 80 vs 100

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am rebuilding some indexes in Azure SQL using a fill factor of 80 (recommended by the company who developed the application, who are not experts on the database) and after doing this queries got a LOT slower. We noticed that now they were taking a longer time in "Network I/O". Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Comment: The slowdown is attributable to async_network_io waits?  That's unrelated to the index rebuild.  The rebuild will recalc stats which can change plans.  Use Query Store to monitor  query plans over time. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: async_network_io` is usually caused by slow client apps, or by poor external networks. `FILL_FACTOR` often makes things *slower* because you need to read 25% more pages, it's only really necessary if your indexes keep getting very fragmented.

Answer (score 0):

Fillfactor is not a silver bullet and has it's tradeoffs. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5908/what-is-the-best-value-for-fill-factor-in-sql-server/

It is important to note which effect the lower fillfactor value has on the underlying data pages and index pages, which comprise your table:
There is now 20% more storage allocated for data pages for the same number of records!
This causes increased I/O. Depending on your Azure storage/compute plan you may be hitting a ceiling and need to bump up you IOPS.

Now, if you are not running out of IOPS, there's more to look into. Is it possible that the index rebuild operation had not completed yet and index is not being used for query optimization? A Profiler/Execution plan can confirm this.

I'd say that if you have a very large table and want to speed things up dramatically, your best bet is partitioning on the column most commonly used to address the data.
See also: https://www.sqlshack.com/database-table-partitioning-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Try to identify queries returning large data sets to client hosts.  Large result sets may lead to unnecessary network utilization and client application processing. Make sure queries are returning only what is needed using filtering and aggregations, and make sure no duplicates are being returned unnecesarily.

Another possible cause of that wait on Azure SQL may be the client application doesn't fetch results fast enough and doesn't notify Azure SQL that the result set has been received. On the client appliation side, store the results in memory first and only then doing more processing. Make sure the lient application is not under stress and that makes it unable to get the results faster.

One last thing, make sure Azure SQL and the appliation are on the same region, and there is not transfer of data over different regions or zones.